# perl called with 2 bind variables when 0 are needed

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

i have this code:

```
    my (@matches, @vars);  

    if ($date_to) {
            push(@matches, q{ m.mentioned_at <= ? });
            push(@vars, $date_to);
        }

        if ($person) {
            push(@matches, q{ t.name like ? });
            push(@vars, $person);
        }
    if ($show) {
            push(@matches, q{ t.name like ? });
            push(@vars, $show);
        }  
    if (@vars){
        my $where = join (' and ', @matches);
        $where = qq{where $where} if @matches  
        $res = $db->do({ page => $.p, per_page => $.s }, q{
                      select m.id, m.body, m.link,
                      count(distinct(m.id)) as num_items
                      from mentions m
                      $where 
                      group by m.id, m.body, m.link,
                      order by m.created_at desc
               }, @vars );
     }   

     print STDERR Dumper ($where);    
     $VAR1 = 'where  m.mentioned_at <= ?  and  t.name like ? ';`  
     print STDERR Dumper (@vars);   
     $VAR1 = '2012/06/01';  
     $VAR2 = 'Adby Phil';`
```

Why do i have this ERROR:

```
called with 2 bind variables when 0 are needed  
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference
```

It seems like it does not see the $where clause.

Comment: What is $db?  That's not a typical DBI->do call...

Comment: In the second argument to the  `do` method, you use the `q{}` quote operator. Variables are not interpolated inside, so you pass the literal string `$where`. Is that intentional? Use the `qq{}` operator to get the contents of `$where` into your query.

Comment: @BrianPhillips, my $db = DBIx::DataStore->new('www');

Comment: @amon - that should've been an answer, not a comment! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think you got the order of your parameters to `do()` switched:

```
$rv  = $dbh->do($statement, \%attr, @bind_values);
```

Looks like you have \%attr first, then $statement.

Also, be aware that `do()` doesn't return a statement handle, so you can't fetch the data. You may want a more traditional prepare and execute sequence.

Comment: This is good advice, but it doesn't address the actual problem the OP was having.  The $db variable is not a DBI handle, and the SQL needed to be double-quoted so that the `$where` clause is interpolated.

Comment: OK. I assumed it was a DBI handle.